# Mesos-master failed to start when running mesos-start-cluster.sh

Tags: apache, mesos

When I ran the mesos-start-cluster.sh after configured mesos-master-env and mesos-slave/agent-env files, the display showed normally. The command's output as following:

```
root@heron02:/home/yitian# ./mesosinstall/sbin/mesos-start-cluster.sh 
Starting mesos-master on heron02
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2 heron02 /home/yitian/mesosinstall/sbin/mesos-daemon.sh mesos-master </dev/null >/dev/null
Starting mesos-agent on heron06
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2 heron06 /home/yitian/mesosinstall/sbin/mesos-daemon.sh mesos-agent </dev/null >/dev/null
Starting mesos-agent on heron07
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2 heron07 /home/yitian/mesosinstall/sbin/mesos-daemon.sh mesos-agent </dev/null >/dev/null
Everything's started!
```

However, when I try to stop the mesos cluster and run the mesos-stop-cluster command, the display showed the error message:

```
root@heron02:/home/yitian# ./mesosinstall/sbin/mesos-stop-cluster.sh 
Stopping mesos-agent on heron06
Stopping mesos-agent on heron07
Stopping mesos-master on heron02
mesos-master: no process found
Everything's stopped!
```

This means mesos-master start filed. The configuration files is no problem, and two agent hosts start success. 
In addition, the mesos-master-env.sh content is:

```
# Some options you're likely to want to set:
# export MESOS_log_dir=/var/log/mesos
export MESOS_log_dir=/home/yitian/mesosdata/log
export MESOS_work_dir=/home/yitian/mesosdata/data
export MESOS_ZK=zk://heron01:2181/mesos
export MESOS_quorum=1
```

And the mesos-slave/agent-env.sh content is:

```
# The mesos master URL to contact. Should be host:port for
# non-ZooKeeper based masters, otherwise a zk:// or file:// URL.
export MESOS_master=heron01:5050
export MESOS_log_dir=/home/yitian/mesosdata/log
export MESOS_work_dir=/home/yitian/mesosdata/run
#export MESOS_isolation=cgroups
```

The problem is mesos-master process cannot start, and the mesos ui(http://heron01:5050) can't open. What's the matter with it?

Comment: Is your question about `mesos-master: no process found` at the end of the stop-script output?

Comment: Also, can you post the contents of your `masters` file?

Comment: I have edited this question. And my question is mesos-master start failed using mesos-start-cluster.sh command. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @YitianZhang Could you put up some error logs? Maybe in you system log file, i.e. /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog.

Comment: I think, you do not need to use this in your configuration: **export MESOS_ZK=zk://heron01:2181/mesos
export MESOS_quorum=1**.